# SQL Split MM and YY and Concat with String

Tags: sql, date, teradata, concatenation

thanks for your help in advance!

I have a date field (A.event_dt) which I am using to create new columns as follows (this goes all the way through to December).

```
to_char(A.event_dt, 'YYYYMM') as Event_Month,

case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.emp_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr, Event_Month order by A.event_dt asc) = 1  then 1 else 0 end as Unique_Event,


count(distinct concat(B.emp_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr, A.event_dt)),

case when CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'MM')(char(2)) = '06' then 1 else '' end as Jun,
case when CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'MM')(char(2)) = '07' then 1 else '' end as Jul,
case when CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'MM')(char(2)) = '08' then 1 else '' end as Aug,
case when CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'MM')(char(2)) = '09' then 1 else '' end as Sep,
case when CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'MM')(char(2)) = '10' then 1 else '' end as Oct,
```

I would like to add the YY as well.

SAMPLE DATA, CURRENT OUTPUT AND DESIRED DATA OUTPUT:

```
....EVENT_DT.....CURRENT OUTPUT......DESIRED DATA OUTPUT
....1/31/2020..........Jan................Jan20
....2/35/2019..........Feb................Feb19
....3/15/2020..........Mar................Mar20
```

DESIRED OUTPUT FORMAT:

```
....EVENT_DT.....Feb19......Jan20..........Mar20
....2/25/2019........1..........................
....1/31/2020..................1................
....3/15/2020..............................1
```

EDIT:
I have tried the code below however am getting an error:
(expected something like ',' between the 'concat' keyword and '('.):

```
case when CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'MM')(char(2)) = '06' then 1 else '' end as concat('Jun',CAST(A.event_dt as DATE FORMAT 'YY')(char(2)))
```

EDIT:
I have also tried this code however am getting an error:
"something like a name or a unicode delimied identifier between the 'AS' keyword and the '('.

```
case when extract(month from A.ramp_dt) = '12' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')),
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '01' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')),
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '02' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Hello there....I have modified my original post with the information requested.

Comment: `extract(month from event_dt)` returns a numeric month. You can't create column aliases dynamically.

Comment: @dnoeth  ....  Hi there - I modified my query to use 'extract' method.  I'm still trying to create column aliases.  Latest attempt indicates error:

case when extract(month from A.ramp_dt) = '12' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')),
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '01' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')),
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '02' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))

Comment: Again, you can't create column aliases dynamically. And why should you want it? You already know which month you want in that column and what if there are two rows from February 2019 & 2020?

Comment: @dnoeth ... hi there....yes, that is why i am trying to bring in the YYYY.  There will only be 12 months of data.

the display i am trying to achieve is as follows:


.EVENT_DT.....Feb19......Jan20..........Mar20

........................................................................................1/31/2020.......................1..................................................................................2/25/2019......................................1..........................

....3/15/2020............................................1

(there's a better visual in my post)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just use [`to_char()`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/he2a_fFPveMN9cjMlF3Tqg)?

```
to_char(a.event_dt, 'MMMMYY')
```

Comment: Hello there.  I would like to see the data represented in columns as I am also counting unique instances. How would I incorporate this in a case statement ?

Answer (score 0):

I always use ISO dates for this type of work.
And the 35th of February is not a valid date, so I made it the 25th of February.

With that, you can do it all with the `TO_CHAR()` function on a `DATE` type.

Like here:

```
-- this is test input, don't use in your query
WITH
dt(dt) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2020-01-31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-02-25'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-03-15'
)
-- end of test input; real query starts here
SELECT
  dt AS event_dt
, TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon') AS current_output
, TO_CHAR(dt,'MonYY') AS desired_output
FROM dt;
-- out   event_dt  | current_output | desired_output 
-- out ------------+----------------+----------------
-- out  2020-01-31 | Jan            | Jan20
-- out  2019-02-25 | Feb            | Feb19
-- out  2020-03-15 | Mar            | Mar20
```

Comment: Hi there - thanks for your reply!

So I have many more event_dt then shown...i have approx. 3K rows in my dataset.

How would i modify this statement to make it more dynamic?

WITH
dt(dt) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2020-01-31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-02-25'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-03-15'
)

Comment: Just don't use the CTE.  Select from your actual table.

Comment: @Andrew ... Hi there - The problem is i'm also trying to create column aliases.  Using the MonYY.

My latest 'attempt' indicates an error:  "something like a name or a unicode delimied identifier between the 'AS' keyword and the '('.

case when extract(month from A.ramp_dt) = '12' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')),
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '01' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')),
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '02' then 1 else '' end as (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))

Comment: Whatever comes after the `AS` keyword is expected to be a column name, not an expression. If it does not comply with the standards for object names in a database, you have to enclose it into double quotes, so `case when extract(month from A.ramp_dt) = '01' then 1 else '' end as "(to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))"` where the result of either `1` or `0` will be in a column named `(to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))` . I bet that is not quite what you expect. Can you just paste into your question a small expected result set, in the format as I show in my response , the lines beginning with `-- out` ?

Comment: @marcothesane...Hi there!  so, i changed the code adding the double-quotes:
case when extract(month from A.ramp_dt) = '12' then 1 else '' end as "(to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))",
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '01' then 1 else '' end as "(to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))",
case when extract(month from  A.ramp_dt) = '02' then 1 else '' end as "(to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))"

however, these are the COLUMN TITLES I am receiving:
(to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')) (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY')) (to_char(A.ramp_dt, 'MonYYYY'))
    1 

my post contains a sample of desired output

Comment: @marcothesane....ideally the column names in this case should read:
   
....EVENT_DT.....Feb19......Jan20..........Mar20..............................................................................................2/25/2019..........1.......................
....1/31/2020...........................1................
....3/15/2020..............................................1...

Comment: @marcothesane....there's a better visual of the desired output FORMAT in my posting

Comment: So: A) you want to add columns to contain "counters", and B) you want the columns to contain names that you assign dynamically. That means : Pivoting (that would be a series of `MAX(CASE ... WHEN .. THEN 1 END) AS Feb20` together with a `GROUP BY` for A); and SQL generating SQL for B).

Comment: @marcothesane ... yes however the YY will change and so I am trying to figure out how to concat the MM and YY, by pulling the YY from event_dt.

Answer (score 0):

This now needs a complete new answer, and it's more complicated than you might expect.
I use Teradata volatile tables. One for your (or my ...) exemplary input, one vor a verticalized output.

I use the verticalized volatile table:
a) as input for generating a pivoting query script
b) as input for the very script that I generate

That means that you need to run the script you generate in the same session that you started, otherwise your volatile table disappears in the meantime.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE dt(event_dt) 
-- your input
AS (
          SELECT DATE '2019-01-31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-04-25'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-07-15'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-15'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-01-31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-04-25'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-07-15'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-10-15'
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS 
;

-- create a vertical table
-- count, for safety, if you have several events
-- per day.
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vertical_per_month 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS 
AS (
  SELECT
     event_dt
  ,  YEAR(event_dt)*100+MONTH(event_dt) AS yearmonth
  , TO_CHAR(event_dt,'MonYY')          AS desired_output
  , COUNT(*) AS occ_count
  FROM dt
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS 
;

-- test query ....
-- SELECT * FROM vertical_per_month;
-- out   event_dt  | yearmonth | desired_output | occ_count 
-- out ------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
-- out  2019-01-31 |    201901 | Jan19          |         1
-- out  2019-04-25 |    201904 | Apr19          |         1
-- out  2019-07-15 |    201907 | Jul19          |         1
-- out  2019-10-15 |    201910 | Oct19          |         1
-- out  2020-01-31 |    202001 | Jan20          |         1
-- out  2020-04-25 |    202004 | Apr20          |         1
-- out  2020-07-15 |    202007 | Jul20          |         1
-- out  2020-10-15 |    202010 | Oct20          |         1

-- write the output of the query below to a file,
-- and execute that file. This is how you do that in 
-- the psql front end batch processor of PostreSQL
-- check the syntax of BTEQ yourself ...
-- do not align output
\a
-- tuples only, no column names, no row count
\t
-- redirect output to "tmp.sql"
\o tmp.sql
SELECT 
  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yearmonth)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'SELECT'||CHR(10)||'  event_dt'||CHR(10)||', '
    ELSE ', '
  END
||'MAX('
  ||'CASE desired_output WHEN '''||desired_output||''''
  ||' THEN '||occ_count::VARCHAR(5)
  ||' END'
||') AS "'||desired_output||'"'
|| CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yearmonth DESC)
    WHEN 1 THEN CHR(10)||'FROM vertical_per_month'
              ||CHR(10)||'GROUP BY 1;'
    ELSE ''
  END AS "-- pivot query"
FROM vertical_per_month
ORDER BY yearmonth;
-- this output below; to file, and then execute ...
-- out SELECT
-- out   event_dt
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Jan19' THEN 1 END) AS "Jan19"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Apr19' THEN 1 END) AS "Apr19"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Jul19' THEN 1 END) AS "Jul19"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Oct19' THEN 1 END) AS "Oct19"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Jan20' THEN 1 END) AS "Jan20"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Apr20' THEN 1 END) AS "Apr20"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Jul20' THEN 1 END) AS "Jul20"
-- out , MAX(CASE desired_output WHEN 'Oct20' THEN 1 END) AS "Oct20"
-- out FROM vertical_per_month
-- out GROUP BY 1;

-- show the "(NULL)" literal in case of NULL values
\pset null (NULL)
-- stop outputting to "tmp.sql" and flush the file to disk.
\o
-- align again ( "\a" is a toggle)
\a
-- show more than just tuples again ("\t" is a toggle, too)
\t
-- run the freshly created "tmp.sql" on the still existing
-- volatile table
\i tmp.sql
-- out   event_dt  | Jan19  | Apr19  | Jul19  | Oct19  | Jan20  | Apr20  | Jul20  | Oct20  
-- out ------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
-- out  2019-01-31 |      1 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL)
-- out  2019-04-25 | (NULL) |      1 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL)
-- out  2019-07-15 | (NULL) | (NULL) |      1 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL)
-- out  2019-10-15 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |      1 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL)
-- out  2020-01-31 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |      1 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL)
-- out  2020-04-25 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |      1 | (NULL) | (NULL)
-- out  2020-07-15 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |      1 | (NULL)
-- out  2020-10-15 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |      1
```